# Django duplicate entry

Tags: django

How would you duplicate a data entry in Django/

The model has data in it. What would be the best way to save an entire model entry into new record and update id to new one.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? Are you trying to duplicate a model? Is this something you want to do manually? Or should visiting a webpage duplicate the entry? Try and give us some details to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first page in search results, seems to do the thing you need: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1040/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update